# How to update rowData list when new rows are added in ag-grid angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular8, ag-grid

How to update rowdata, once new rows are added dynamically in ag-grid.

```
gridApi: GridApi;
```

grid headers defined

```
diagnosticDefs = [{
        headerName: 'Diagnostic',
        field: 'diagnostic',
    },
    {
        headerName: 'Description',
        field: 'description'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'Discovery Date',
        field: 'discoveryDate'
    }
];

diagnosticRowData = [];

defaultColDef = {
    editable: true
}
```

adding a new row dynamically on click of add new row button

```
addNewDiagnostic() {
    const newRow = [{
        diagnostic: '',
        description: '',
        discoveryDate: ''
    }];
    this.gridApi.updateRowData({
        add: newRow
    });
}
```

Ag-grid added in html

```
 <div class="text-right mb-2"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="addNewDiagnostic()">Add New</button></div>
                <ag-grid-angular #gridApi
                    style="height: 155px; margin: auto"
                    class="ag-theme-balham"
                    [rowData]="diagnosticRowData"
                    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" 
                    [columnDefs]="diagnosticDefs"
                    (gridReady)="onGridReadyDiagnostic($event)">
                </ag-grid-angular>                  
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="saveDiagnostic()">Save</button>
            </div>
```

Added Dynamic rows, but row data is not updated
After adding 3 rows still row data value is empty

```
diagnosticRowData =[];
```

Comment: you could insert it in to the target array when you run `addNewDiagnostic` - they way its currently configured `diagnosticRowData` is the source data for the target grid. i think what you are trying to achieve is to add a row thru the grid api and have that data also populate in `diagnosticRowData` - there is currenlty only one way binding in place, you could try `[(rowData)]='diagnosticRowData'` - to see if two way binding works

Comment: [(rowData)] is not working. Tried this this.diagnosticRowData.push(newRow); which is working.

Comment: then another solution is to push that data into `diagosticRowData` then call `this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(diagnosticRowData)` instead of   `this.gridApi.updateRowData({
        add: newRow
    });`